# mySQL JSON : search array of objects where property value in list

Tags: mysql, json

I have a  `JSON` column, `manifest`, containing an array of objects.
I need to return all table rows where any of the objects in their array have a `slide_id` that is present in a sub select.

The structure of the JSON field is..

```
{ matrix:[
     {
        row:1,
        col:1,
        slide_id:1
     },
     {
        row:1,
        col:2,
        slide_id:5
     }
  ]
}
```

So I want to run something like this....

```
SELECT id FROM presentation WHERE manifest->'$.matrix[*].slide_id' IN ( (SELECT id from slides WHERE date_deleted IS NOT NULL) );
```

But this doesn't work as `manifest->'$.matrix[*].slide_id'` returns a JSON array for each row.

I have managed to get this to work, but its amazingly slow as it scans the whole table...

```
SELECT 
    p.id
FROM 
    (
     SELECT id, 
     manifest->'$.matrix[*].slide_id' as slide_ids 
     FROM `presentation`
    ) p
INNER JOIN `pp_slides` s 
ON JSON_CONTAINS(p.slide_ids, CAST(s.id as json), '$')    
WHERE s.date_deleted IS NOT NULL
```

If I filter it down to an individual presentation ID, then its not too bad, but still takes 700 ms for a presentation with a couple of hundred slides in it.  Is there a cleaner way to do this?

I suppose the best way would be to refactor it to store the matrix as a relational table....